# Ubuntu Desktop 14.04.1 Installation: Partition Sizes for 32Gb of Free Space

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning

I'm fixing to install Ubuntu Desktop 14.04.1 on my ASUS X551-MAV-EB01-B and so far I've cleared away 32Gb so that the free space is for a full installation (**alongside the pre-installed Windows 8.1).**

I've recently installed **Lubuntu** on this space but decided to go for Ubuntu Desktop instead. (After I cleared the space from the Lubuntu install, grub 2 is still on the computer somehow even though I installed it to a partition that is now gone). Creepy but hopefully not problematic.

I'm curious about sizing the partitions I'll be making in the advanced install method. Specifically, `/`, `/home`, and `swap-area`.

Do I even need swap? I have 4Gb RAM. Also I heard somewhere that making a separate `/home` partition is good if dual-booting (which I will be, between just Ubuntu and Windows 8.1). Is that true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a swap area is always a good idea. In short, it's good for memory-consuming programs, as well as hibernation and memory optimization. You should see the ["Why do I need swap?" part](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq) of the SwapFaq for a more detailed explanation.

As for splitting up the partition - I don't know of any benefit for booting, but it is a good approach. The reason for that is that in case anything goes wrong - you can always just format and re-install Ubuntu cleanly **withouth losing any of your actual data** - you just format the root `/` and re-point `/home` to the `home` partition.

I can account that this setup saved me once (even though the initial screw-up was my fault). However, with only 32GB I wouldn't recommend it, as the system partition should have at least 20-25GB of free space on its own.

Comment: Well I can always add to that free space I have right now. Also, if going through the Windows parts of the computer is possible (it was in Lubuntu via mounting in File Manager) then I'm not too worried about storage space for media.

Comment: @PatrickC.James there's no reason you'll see any different behavior in Ubuntu. Lubuntu is just Ubuntu with some features (especially the visual ones) stripped away